# Repeated column in mapping for entity JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, jpa

I am developping a Spring Boot Rest application. 
I generated Entites from tables (mysql) with JPA tools but i have this Error despite i added spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy to **application.propreties**
 :

**Repeated column in mapping for entity: rest.app.domain.ProfilDeUtilisateur column: profil_nom_profil (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")**

Pom.xml :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.41</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
   </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
              <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
              <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
              <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency> 
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.10</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>   
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Application.propreties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/piv_qia
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=aebc3ffd
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl_auto: update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-
strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Thank you.